# Using javascript to search a limited and manually made index

Tags: javascript, search-engine

I have a couple of pages with multimedia content (flash), and I want to be able to search it's contents through an page.

Since it's content isn't searcheable, and I have a document with all the word/image descriptions that are going to appear in each page, I was thinking of writing this content in several pages linking them to the respective page with multimedia content,and use a search engine to index this information.

But this looks like overcomplication. So I though of using javascript and insert each page's keyword to it's own array, and when the user searches it compares with each array and print's:
"This content is available in the following pages:"

This seems simple, but I would like to have some opinions from more experienced people:
- either  for problems that I'm going to run into;
- or better/easier solutions.

I ask that anyone who contributes consider that I'm not that experienced with programming.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
You haven't described a data structure so I'll assume an *Array* of *Object* s.

Say you have this data structure,

```
var all_items = [
    {url: 'a', title:'First Entry', description:'Foo'},
    {url: 'b', title:'Second Entry', description:'Bar'},
    {url: 'c', title:'Third Entry', description:'FooBar'}
    // etc..
];
```

You could write a search function based on `.filter` like this

```
function search(arr, str, url /* =true */, title /* =true */, desc /* =false */) {
    var src_fnc;
    // set true defaults
    if (undefined === url) url = true;
    if (undefined === title) title = true;
    // toBool
    url = url && true || false;
    title = title && true || false;
    desc = desc && true || false;
    // make function
    src_fnc = function (e) {
        if (url && e.url.indexOf(str) >= 0) return true;
        if (title && e.title.indexOf(str) >= 0) return true;
        if (desc && e.description.indexOf(str) >= 0) return true;
        return false;
    };
    return arr.filter(src_fnc);
}
```

and then invoke it

```
search(all_items, 'ir');
/*  [
        {url: 'a', title:'First Entry', description:'Foo'},
        {url: 'c', title:'Third Entry', description:'FooBar'}
    ] */
```

Comment: Hmm... I was considering having a separate array object for each page and have the engine check each string for a match (since people will search specific words most of the time). And then if a match was found it would return: "Match found in these pages:

- Module 1 - Food;

- Module 5 - Travel."

Thanks, btw.

Comment: For that, just run this function `x` times, where `x` is the number of _Array_ s you have, using the appropriate array instead of `all_items` (along with other fixes to make the function match your data).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Do you have any other suggestion? Is this a bad practice? Are there other, more efficent, ways? Is yours better? I'm really trying to learn and I know I shouldn't do half-assed coding...

Comment: Well it depends on what you have and you haven't shared, so my answer is based on assumption. There is a different way, which is to make an **iterator** or "generator". If you use that method, you don't have to load everything into memory at once and further, you can introduce little gaps using `window.setTimeout` which will mean the page doesn't freeze over huge amounts of data.